# How to start a new Logstash instance when another goes down

Tags: database, logstash

We have a requirement, where we send DB events to one logstash instance. If one Logstash instance goes down, another logstash instance should start automatically. Both logstash will be deployed in same machine with different node name, example (active node and optional active node)

Please let us know how to handle logstash clustering for DB events.

Comment: What do you mean with *we send DB events to one logstash instance*? I assume you use the Logstash JDBC input plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) to fetch database records with a sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

use lvs+keepalived, Two hosts use a VIP

Comment: Can you please explain me this in detail